# write in 3 edittext fields at same time

Tags: android

I am writing a calculator for drawing graphs. I am using 3 editTexts; the first and second are for the extreme values and the third is for the function. I do not need the keyboard, so I hide it and use my own button, but when I write for example "11" in one box then it shows in the other.
I would be happy with any helpful suggestions. 
[a part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfA6v.png)

```
public void disableButtonClick(EditText txt) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        txt.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        txt.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
    }
    else {
        txt.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        txt.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    }
}

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext3);
    //hide soft keyboard  :
    disableButtonClick(editText);
    disableButtonClick(editText1);
    disableButtonClick(editText2);
  button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText1.setText(editText1.getText()+"0");
            editText2.setText(editText2.getText()+"0");
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"0");
        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText1.setText(editText1.getText()+"1");
            editText2.setText(editText2.getText()+"1");
            editText.setText(editText.getText()+"1");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, for any `EditText` you create, an [addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) listens for updates/changes to the content of the `EditText`. In simple terms, you can detect whether any change has been made to the text in your EditText using a `addTextChangedListener`.

Here's a potential solution to your problem: Listen for changes on *`edittext1`* and simply set updated text to *`edittext2`* and *edittext3*. In technical terms, this means setting an `addTextChangedListener` to *`edittext1`* and then updating *`edittext2`* and *`edittext3`* anytime the text in *`edittext1`* changes. Here's the implementation:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    boolean considerChange = false;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (considerChange){ 
            editText2.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
            editText.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
            }
            considerChange = !considerChange; // flip the boolean
    }
});
```

> PS: I added the boolean `considerChange` because each of the methods
>   in `addTextChangedListener` are recursive.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: i still have the same problem

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I mean.. from what I can infer, you want all your EditTexts to be updated every time editText1 is.

Comment: the problem is that my EditTexts is updated every time editText1 is, what i want is :each edittexts is ubpdated only if i clik on it... when write in edText1,the rest is not effected

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText1.setText("write everything");
    }
});

editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        editText2.setText(editText1.getText() + "");
        editText.setText(editText1.getText() + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {                
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

add imports

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
```

Comment: where i should write this code?inside "onClick" method?